# Tkinter Drop down Menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter, user-controls

I am trying to add entry fields based on a Tkinter dropdown menu but I am not sure that I am doing it correctly. When I select an option on one of the drop down menu I am not getting any new entry fields popping up. The code is what I have so far. I have also tried putting the if statements in an external function and putting a command inside the OptionMenu and it still did not work.

```
    from Tkinter import *


def callback():
    numQues = int(E1.get())
    i = 0
    while i <= numQues:
        variable = StringVar(top)
        variable.set("Questions Type") # default value
        w = OptionMenu(top, variable, "Short Answer", "Multiple Choice", "Fill in the Blank",
                  "True of False", "Matching", "Ordering")

        w.grid(row = i*2+2, column=0)
        ques = StringVar(top, value='Question')
        ans = StringVar(top, value='Answer')
        choice = StringVar(top, value='Answer Choices')

        if variable.get() == "Short Answer":
            q = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = ques)
            q.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 2, columnspan=2)
            a = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            a.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 4, columnspan=2)

        if variable.get()  == "Multiple Choice":
            q = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = ques)
            q.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 2, columnspan=2)
            c = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            c.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 4, columnspan=2)
            a = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            a.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 6, columnspan=2)

        if variable.get()  == "True or False":
            q = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = ques)
            q.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 2, columnspan=2)
            a = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            a.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 6, columnspan=2)

        if variable.get()  == "Fill in the Blank":
            q = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = ques)
            q.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 2, columnspan=2)
            a = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            a.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 4, columnspan=2)

        if variable.get()  == "Ordering":
            q = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = ques)
            q.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 2, columnspan=2)
            a = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = answ)
            a.grid(row=i*2+2, column = 4, columnspan=2)

        i = i+1


top = Tk()
top.geometry("600x600")
top.title("eCampus Quiz Developer")
L1 = Label(top, text="How many questions will the quiz be?")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `option_changed`? Where and how do you define it?

Comment: sorry that was from an old piece of code from attempting something else that did not work

Comment: Also what is `q`?

Comment: q is an entry box I want added if the drop down menu selection is that of the if statement

Comment: sorry see my edited code

Comment: BTW, I am not seeing any difference between those codes under if statements. If they are all same, why do you have if's there?

Comment: some are a little different. I was going to go back and just combine some of them into one if statement. This si just a small snippet of where I am trying to go with this. Where I want to go is much more intricate but I have to get this part working first.

Comment: https://repl.it/KWRT Sadly I don't have time to create a complete answer but I hope this snippet should point you to the right way or other answerers to make a complete answer.